# Powershell command line history expansion

Tags: powershell

I would like to have in Powershell something similar I had in a Fish shell.
With every new keystroke e.g. Tab I would like to expand/select one part of some old command., please see the picture I attached.
[image]

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.FullName (Get-ChildItem $_ | Measure-Object).Count}
```

e.g

- when I press the tab key the first time -> '-directory' will be
  selected
- when I press the tab key a second time -> 'I' will be selected
- when I press the tab key a third time -> 'ForEeach-Object' will be
  selected

etc.

Answer (score 3):

PSReadline 2.1 does that.  Either install it for powershell 5.1, or install powershell 7.2 that comes with it.  You have to enable it with `Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History`.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/

Actually, PSReadLine 2.2 is in Release Candidate:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/psreadline-2-2-rc/